# Как отсортировать по кириллице многомерный массив по значению?

Tags: php

```
[
  1 => [
    'id' => 100,
    'value' => 35,
    'name' => 'Первое название',
  ],
  2 => [
    'id' => 101,
    'value' => 39,
    'name' => 'Второе название',
  ],
  3 => [
    'id' => 102,
    'value' => 42,
    'name' => 'Третье название',
  ],
];
```

Собственно в латиницей проблем нет, решений полно, а вот как быть с русскими символами..

Comment: Можете уточнить задачу? В каком плане отсортировать?

Comment: @makcim512 отсортировать массив в алфавитном порядке по значению name

Comment: Берете это полно и берете это [setlocale](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.setlocale.html)  или берете `iconv` или бегаете по `chr`. И будет вам счастье

Comment: Вам нужно вернуть такой же массив или только значения сортированые?

Answer (score -1):

php7:

```
$array =
[
    1 => [
        'id' => 100,
        'value' => 35,
        'name' => 'Первое название',
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 101,
        'value' => 39,
        'name' => 'Второе название',
    ],
    3 => [
         'id' => 102,
         'value' => 42,
         'name' => 'Третье название',
    ],
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];
});
```

[Посмотреть результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34735d05b0df6c1f39970562996aacc1034de48e)

Comment: Если локаль установлена по умолчанию без юникода, это решение работать не будет. Что и говорит автор вопроса, если вы, конечно читать умеете. И судя по этому, у него проблема с локалью.